# Showing $p$-adic topology is a neighborhood topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am working through exercise 2.27 of Brown's *Topology and Groupoids*. In the exercise, we consider set $X = \mathbb{Z}$ and define a $p$-adic topology for fixed $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ by neighborhoods $N_r$ of $x \in X$ as $$ N_r = \{ n + mp^r \mid m = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \dots \}$$.

The exercise is to show that this is indeed a valid neighborhood topology. I'm having trouble showing the second axiom holds:

> If $N$ is a subset of $X$ containing a neighborhood of $x$, then $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

To get a feel for how to show $N$ can be expressed as $\{ n + mp^r \}$ for some fixed $p$ and $r \in \mathbb{Z}$, I wanted to try some examples. One such example is:

Let $p = 3$. Then one neighborhood of $6 \in X$ is $$ M = \{ 6 + 3^2m \mid m = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \dots \}. $$ The set $N = M \cup \{ 2 \}$ is a subset of $X$ that contains a neighborhood of $6$ so if we indeed have a neighborhood topology then it is possible to find some $r$ such that $N = \{ 6 + 3^rm \mid m = 0, \pm 1, \dots \}$. However, I can't seem to do this and, in the process, find a plausible way to prove that the $p$-adic topology satisfies the axiom. Since I'm having so much trouble making progress with such a basic case, I'm led to believe that my setup is incorrect.

Any hints would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps my understanding of the definition of neighborhoods is incorrect? The given definition is that $N$ is a p-adic neighborhood if it contains the integers $n + mp^r$, but I've been working with the assumption that $N$ must be exactly the integers given by $n + mp^r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably misunderstood the statement of the exercise, since the sets $p^r \mathbb{Z}$ are not a full family of neighbourhoods of zero (I am translating to zero for simplicity) for the $p$-adic topology - rather, they are a *basis* of neighbourhoods. The full family of neighbourhoods is the collection of all sets $U$ containing one of the $p^r \mathbb{Z}$. It is trivial that these satisfy your axiom. (They are actually the smallest family containing the sets $p^r \mathbb{Z}$ for all $r$ and satisfying this axiom).

Comment: For more detail: in the *usual* (archimedean) topology on $\mathbb R$, a *basis* for the neighbourhoods of $0$ is the set of open balls centered at zero. It is not a full set of neighbourhoods. The sets $p^r \mathbb{Z}$ are the exact $p$-adic analogue: they are the $p$-adic balls centered at zero.